# Custom route mistaken for object id in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

**I have the following route:**

```
 view_all_styles        /styles/view_all(.:format)                styles#view_all
```

**When I point my broswer at `xyz.com/styles/view_all` I receive the error:**

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound at /styles/view_all
Couldn't find Style with id=view_all
```

**I'm also routed to the show action??**

```
Request parameters  
{"action"=>"show", "controller"=>"styles", "id"=>"view_all"}
```

Comment: You need to provide the content of `styles#view_all`, probably you use `Style.find(params[:id])`, and it's complained about not finding this record.

Comment: I have the action in my controller

Comment: Why is `view_all` not just using the `index` route? That's what it's for.

Comment: I'm trying to sort out a problem with google pagination crawling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you've got your routes defined in the wrong order - you'll want to define your custom route before the resource routes of styles. Otherwise, you'll run into exactly this problem.

Since your route, `/styles/view_all` also fits into the route for #show, `/styles/:id` ('view_all' being the :id), it will match and pass along the request to #show before it even tries to match your custom route.